# Is “in so unpleasant a manner” actually grammatical in English? Why?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, negative-polarity-items, big-mess-construction

I guess "in so unpleasant a manner" is the same as "in such an unpleasant manner". But what is the grammatical construction of the former? The whole sentence is:

> He would not have sacked her **in so unpleasant a manner**.

Why did the writer of this sentence use this construction?

Answer (score 2):

*In so unpleasant a manner* means *in a manner that was so unpleasant.* It's quite a common construction in English, as an alternative to *in such a...* The writer used it because that was their stylistic choice.

"You shouldn't stay out of doors for long on so cold a day."
"You must be tired after so long a journey."  etc. etc.